# Chat head Click events

Tags: android, overlay, imagebutton

I used an online tutorial to create a simple application which adds ImageButton to the window. By window I mean that the ImageButton is displayed above the rest of the activities. It is always visible.

I don't know how to handle click events for the chat head. I set a onClickListener but it doesn't do anything.

Here's my ChatHeadService.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ChatHeadService extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView chatHead;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Not used
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        chatHead = new ImageButton(this);
        chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
        chatHead.setClickable(true);
        chatHead.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


            }
        });

        chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    params.x = initialX
                            + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY
                            + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (chatHead != null)
            windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should invoke performClick() when you think there is a click event. Perhaps in ACTION_UP branch?

Comment: Here is a great tutorial that explains how to create chat heads. https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/create-chat-heads-like-facebook-messenger-32f7f1a62064#.624cs5hzy

Answer (score 9):

try this :

```
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if( (Math.abs(initialTouchX - event.getRawX())<5) && (Math.abs(initialTouchY - event.getRawY())<5) )
                        {
                            Log.e(TAG,"It's a click ! ");
                        }
                        else Log.e(TAG,"you moved the head");
                        return true;
```

Comment: This is the best solution. I am not in favour of even implementing boolean check in ACTION_MOVE.